# Google Prediction API, Hello Prediction: error - Too few arguments

Tags: python, argparse, google-prediction

Today is my first day trying out Google Prediction API on Anaconda Python (Ubuntu Linux).

I wanted to try out the Hello Prediction starter code [prediction.py](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/prediction/prediction.py) using the following:

```
    $ python prediction.py --object_name="mymodelid/mybucket" --id="myidentifier"
```

exactly how it is advised in the code documentation.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
    usage: pred.py [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                   [--noauth_local_webserver]
                   [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                   [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
                   object_name id
    pred.py: error: too few arguments
```

I've tried debugging, but I get lost within the `argparse` package methods.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Prerequisites to reproduction of this code include uploading data to Google Storage. Steps can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs/hello_world#prerequisites).

Comment: Cannot reproduce with python 2.7.6

Comment: Hey @TimCastelijns, I have added an edit line. There should be a few prerequisite steps, which I had completely forgot to mention earlier. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message you should be using

```
$ python prediction.py mymodelid/mybucket myidentifier
```

It expects 2 strings, without flags.

```
usage: pred.py [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
               ...
               object_name id
```

You can also include values like '--auth_host_hame=Joe', but that's in `[]`, so is optional.  There isn't an '[--id ID]' term in the usage line.